# SQL INSERT INTO SELECT error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: sql-server

I am currently trying to take data from one table and insert it into another based on a number of constraints. 
Unfortunately when I run the script I get the following error:

> error converting data type nvarchar to float

and I'm unsure how I can change the query to fix this. Both the source and destination tables have all fields as `nvarchar(255)` and I don't quite know what to do.

The **SQL** query is as follows:

```
Insert into Database.dbo.ML_Records ([AccountNumber]
  ,[House Number]
  ,[Street]
  ,[City]
  ,[Postalcode]
  ,[County]
  ,[Phone]
  ,[Country]
  ,[Account Type]
  ,[Nr_of_Dependents]
  ,[FirstName]
  ,[LasName]
  ,[Title]
  ,[JobTitle]
  ,[Email]
  ,[LeadType]
  ,[LeadSource]
  ,[LeadOrigin]
  ,[CampaignCode]
  ,[Contact_Preference]
  ,[Product_Interest]
  ,[NewServicesForCustomer]
  ,[Lead_Description])

Select  [Account Number]  as [AccountNumber]
    , NULL      as [House Number]
    , [Address Line 1] + ' ' + [Address Line 2]                                                                                                                                                     as [Street]
    , Town                                                                                                                                                                                          as [City]
    , Postcode                                                                                                                                                                                      as [Postalcode]
    , County                                                                                                                                                                                        as [County]
    , case when [Telephone] is null then [Mobile] else [Telephone] end                                                                                                                              as [Phone]
    , NULL                                                                                                                                                                                          as [Country]
    , case when [Account Type 2] is not null and [Identical Accounts] = 'No' then [Account Type 2] else [Account Type 1] end                        as [Account Type]
    , [Number of Dependents]                                        as [Nr_of_Employees_Company_Modelled]
    , [Forename]                                                                                                                                                                                    as [FirstName]
    , [Surname]                                                                                                                                                                                     as [LastName]
    , [Title]                                                                                                                                                                                       as [Title]
    , [Job Title]                                                                                                                                                                                   as [JobTitle]
    , case when [Email] is null then [Site Email] else [Email]  end                                                                                                                                 as [Email]
    , NULL                                                                                                                                                                                          as [LeadType]
    , NULL                                                                                                                                                                                          as [LeadSource]
    , NULL                                                                                                                                                                                          as [LeadOrigin]
    , case when ((([Email] is not NULL or [Site Email] is not null) and [Do NOT EMAIL] <> 'Y') and (([Telephone] is not null or [Mobile] is not null) and [DO NOT TELEPHONE] <> 'Y' and [Records on TPS] is NULL and [Records on CTPS] is NULL)) and [CAT Status] = 0 then 'A-B2F-CL-TM/EM-M2-CAT0-GL'
            when ((([Email] is not NULL or [Site Email] is not null) and [Do NOT EMAIL] <> 'Y') and (([Telephone] is not null or [Mobile] is not null) and [DO NOT TELEPHONE] <> 'Y' and [Records on TPS] is NULL and [Records on CTPS] is NULL)) and [CAT Status] = 1 then 'A-B2F-CL-TM/EM-M2-CAT1-GL'
            when ((([Email] is not NULL or [Site Email] is not null) and [Do NOT EMAIL] <> 'Y') and (([Telephone] is not null or [Mobile] is not null) and [DO NOT TELEPHONE] <> 'Y' and [Records on TPS] is NULL and [Records on CTPS] is NULL)) and [CAT Status] = 2 then 'A-B2F-CL-TM/EM-M2-CAT2-GL'
            when ((([Email] is not NULL or [Site Email] is not NULL) AND [Do NOT EMAIL] <> 'Y') and (([Telephone]  is NULL AND [Mobile] is NULL) OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y')) and [CAT Status] = 0 then 'A-B2F-CL-EM-M2-CAT0-GL'
            when ((([Email] is not NULL or [Site Email] is not NULL) AND [Do NOT EMAIL] <> 'Y') and (([Telephone]  is NULL AND [Mobile] is NULL) OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y')) and [CAT Status] = 1 then 'A-B2F-CL-EM-M2-CAT1-GL'
            when ((([Email] is not NULL or [Site Email] is not NULL) AND [Do NOT EMAIL] <> 'Y') and (([Telephone]  is NULL AND [Mobile] is NULL) OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y')) and [CAT Status] = 2 then 'A-B2F-CL-EM-M2-CAT2-GL'
            when ((([Email] is NULL and [Site Email] is null) or [Do NOT EMAIL] = 'Y') and (([Telephone] is not null or [Mobile] is not null) and [DO NOT TELEPHONE] <> 'Y' and [Records on TPS] is NULL and [Records on CTPS] is NULL)) and [CAT Status] = 0 then 'A-B2F-CL-TM-M2-CAT0-GL'
            when ((([Email] is NULL and [Site Email] is null) or [Do NOT EMAIL] = 'Y') and (([Telephone] is not null or [Mobile] is not null) and [DO NOT TELEPHONE] <> 'Y' and [Records on TPS] is NULL and [Records on CTPS] is NULL)) and [CAT Status] = 1 then 'A-B2F-CL-TM-M2-CAT1-GL'
            when ((([Email] is NULL and [Site Email] is null) or [Do NOT EMAIL] = 'Y') and (([Telephone] is not null or [Mobile] is not null) and [DO NOT TELEPHONE] <> 'Y' and [Records on TPS] is NULL and [Records on CTPS] is NULL)) and [CAT Status] = 2 then 'A-B2F-CL-TM-M2-CAT2-GL'
            when ((([Email] is NULL and [Site Email] is null) or [Do NOT EMAIL] = 'Y') and ((([Telephone] is NULL OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y') OR ([Records on TPS] = '1' or [Records on CTPS] = '1')) AND (([Mobile] is NULL OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y') OR ([Records on TPS] = '1' or [Records on CTPS] = '1')))) and [CAT Status] = 0 then 'A-B2F-CL-DM-M2-CAT0-GL'
            when ((([Email] is NULL and [Site Email] is null) or [Do NOT EMAIL] = 'Y') and ((([Telephone] is NULL OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y') OR ([Records on TPS] = '1' or [Records on CTPS] = '1')) AND (([Mobile] is NULL OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y') OR ([Records on TPS] = '1' or [Records on CTPS] = '1')))) and [CAT Status] = 1 then 'A-B2F-CL-DM-M2-CAT1-GL'
            when ((([Email] is NULL and [Site Email] is null) or [Do NOT EMAIL] = 'Y') and ((([Telephone] is NULL OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y') OR ([Records on TPS] = '1' or [Records on CTPS] = '1')) AND (([Mobile] is NULL OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y') OR ([Records on TPS] = '1' or [Records on CTPS] = '1')))) and [CAT Status] = 2 then 'A-B2F-CL-DM-M2-CAT2-GL' end as [CampaignCode]
    , case when ((([Email] is not NULL or [Site Email] is not null) and [Do NOT EMAIL] <> 'Y') and (([Telephone] is not null or [Mobile] is not null) and [DO NOT TELEPHONE] <> 'Y' and [Records on TPS] is NULL and [Records on CTPS] is NULL)) then 'EM/TM'
            when ((([Email] is not NULL or [Site Email] is not NULL) AND [Do NOT EMAIL] <> 'Y') and (([Telephone]  is NULL AND [Mobile] is NULL) OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y')) then 'EM'
            when ((([Email] is NULL and [Site Email] is null) or [Do NOT EMAIL] = 'Y') and (([Telephone] is not null or [Mobile] is not null) and [DO NOT TELEPHONE] <> 'Y' and [Records on TPS] is NULL and [Records on CTPS] is NULL)) then 'TM'
            when ((([Email] is NULL and [Site Email] is null) or [Do NOT EMAIL] = 'Y') and ((([Telephone] is NULL OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y') OR ([Records on TPS] = '1' or [Records on CTPS] = '1')) AND (([Mobile] is NULL OR [DO NOT TELEPHONE] = 'Y') OR ([Records on TPS] = '1' or [Records on CTPS] = '1')))) then 'DM' end as [Contact_Preference]

    , NULL                                                                                                                                  as [Product_Interest]
    , NULL                                                                                                                                  as [NewServicesForCustomer]
    , [CAT Status] +',' + [Competitor available 1] + ',' + [Competitor available 2] + ',' + [Competitor available 3] + ',' + [Competitor available 4] + ',' + [Competitor available 5] + ',' + [Competitor available 6] + ',' + [Competitor available 7] + ',' + [Competitor available 8] + ',' + [Competitor available 9] + ',' + [Last year accounts paid?] as [Description]
from ML_Pre_Test_Master
where [Commercial premise (yes/no)] <> 'Yes - Closed'
```

Any help you could lend would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are trying to insert a NVARCHAR field into a FLOAT.
Check your SELECT, or if it is the case, convert the field to FLOAT.

Comment: But the source table and the final table both only have NVARCHAR fields, I never specify FLOAT anywhere, so I don't know what to do.

If I were to convert the fields, where exactly would I have to convert them? In the original tables? Or can I put a cast() function somewhere in the query?

Comment: You say all columns in source and destination are varchar(255) but in your case statements you are testing e.g. `[CAT Status] = 0` (and 1, 2 etc) this is a numeric constant so will try to convert [CAT Status] to compare it.

Comment: As far as I knew they were, the templates for the tables were imported in from Excel and when I right click and create table to see the field types they're all coming up as nvarchar(255)
How can I amend the query so that the conversion errors stop?
Sorry I only have a working knowledge of SQL and I've never had to deal with this problem before.

Comment: Execute this query `SELECT [CAT Status] FROM ML_Pre_Test_Master WHERE ISNUMERIC([CAT Status]) = 0` and tell us if it returns any row.

Comment: It has brought back 63 rows, all with NULL entries, the table should have 442 entries and CAT Status should be 0,1 or 2

Comment: I've looked into it and found a small error with the import file, fixed this and now all CAT status rows are numbers, your query is now, not bringing back any rows, the original error is still coming up though

Comment: Script your table dbo.ML_Records as CREATE and post it here. With all the constraints defined on it

Comment: There are so many things wrong here. Column names should not have spaces or special characters. It is just painful to work with. You also seem to have some serious normalization problems. When you have columns numbered 1, 2, 3 etc it is a sure sign something is amiss. What happens when you need to add another one? You have to change the table and every query that touches it. If this were normalized properly you simply add another row to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one of your [CAT Status] row has a letter so while casting sql throwing a error.
Can you check all [CAT Status] variables?

Comment: I've looked into all entries of CAT Status in the source table and they're all numeric, I ran the following query 
SELECT [CAT Status] FROM ML_Pre_Test_Master WHERE ISNUMERIC([CAT Status]) = 0 
and there were no rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Cat Status]... It's being concatinated into the [Descripion] string. Based on other references to that column elsewhere in the query, it would appear to have a numeric data type. Trying to concatinate a numeric data type, using the "+" symbol makes SQL Server think it supposed to be doing math and it tries to convert everything into numerical values.

Comment: But OP said that all columns are `nvarchar`, so it should not be a problem.

Comment: Okay, So I should look at all my different concatenations and make sure that the fields are converted beforehand?

Where in the query should I convert them? In the insert into or select statement? Or in a different section separately?

Comment: You can do it right there in the concation... + CAST([Cat Status] AS NVARCHAR(10)) +...   Or... you can use the CONCAT() function to build the string and let it handle any necessary data type conversions for you.

Comment: Glad to help. :)